# Removing past and current month options from selectbox based on year selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am creating a form that includes two select boxes to allow users to choose a month and year to cancel a membership. The month selected should not be the current month nor past months. I added some jQuery to pre-select the month after the current one, but it still allows users to select a previous month if they want.

What I would like to implement is a script that removes options based on the year selected. For example: If 2016 is selected (and we're in October 2016 now), the script should remove options 1 through 10.

I suspect it is not too complicated, but my knowledge of jQuery is very limited. Thanks in advance.

Codepen: http://codepen.io/ricardoh/pen/vXpdvQ

Here is the HTML:

```
<select id="month">
    <option value="1">January</option>
    <option value="2">February</option>
    <option value="3">March</option>
    <option value="4">April</option>
    <option value="5">May</option>
    <option value="6">June</option>
    <option value="7">July</option>
    <option value="8">August</option>
    <option value="9">September</option>
    <option value="10">October</option>
    <option value="11">November</option>
    <option value="12">December</option>
</select>

<select id="year">
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
    <option value="2018">2018</option>
</select>
```

And the jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    var month = new Date().getMonth() + 1;
    if( month > 12 ) month = 1;
    document.getElementById("month").options[month].selected = true;
});
```

Comment: is it possible for you to make use of database i-e two tables one for saving all the months and one for saving years both have the relation in between them, then fetch months according to year and current date and populate them in select box ?

Comment: @AhmerSaeed that would probably be the smartest way of doing it, but I am trying to stick to HTML and jQuery. Someone posted the solution below.

Comment: Ricardo Andres - i have test the following answer but it has a bug which i already mentioned in that answer's comment you may look it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was working on this while I noticed that the question had been answered and accepted, figured a second answer couldn't hurt.

```js
$(function(){
    var monthElem = document.getElementById('month');
    var yearElem = document.getElementById('year');
    var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
    var createOption = function(monthID) {
        var elem = document.createElement('option');
        elem.value = monthID+1;
        elem.text = months[monthID];
        return elem;
        };
    var evt = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
    yearElem.addEventListener('change', function() {
        var now = new Date(), tmp;
        var month = now.getMonth();
        if(now.getFullYear() === parseInt(this.value)) {
            tmp = month;
            while(tmp >= 0) monthElem.remove(tmp--);
        }
        else {
            tmp = monthElem.length = 0;
            while(tmp < 12) monthElem.add(createOption(tmp), tmp++);
        }
    }, false);
    evt.initEvent('change', false, true);
    yearElem.dispatchEvent(evt);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="month">
    <option value="1">January</option>
    <option value="2">February</option>
    <option value="3">March</option>
    <option value="4">April</option>
    <option value="5">May</option>
    <option value="6">June</option>
    <option value="7">July</option>
    <option value="8">August</option>
    <option value="9">September</option>
    <option value="10">October</option>
    <option value="11">November</option>
    <option value="12">December</option>
</select>

<select id="year">
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
    <option value="2018">2018</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I'm sure you can make all necessary changes from here -- I would recommend that in the case that the current month is December, don't allow the user to be able to select the current year.

Comment: Very interesting. Your approach is slightly different than the other one. I understand better the jQuery hide/show methods and CSS, but this solution is definitely useful to get a better grasp of JavaScript. TYVM for your time.

Comment: it seems like this option works cross-browser while the other one is ignored by Safari. Apparently Apple doesn't believe options should be styled. I'm doing further tests.

Comment: This solution works on all browsers I could test. It is now marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this? [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b7ua6jvv/)

```
function adjustMonths() {
   var thisYear = new Date().getFullYear() + ""; //Get current year
   var nextMonth = new Date().getMonth()+2 + ""; //Get next month
   var selectedYear = $('#year option:selected').val(); //Selected Year
   if (nextMonth .length == 1) {
      nextMonth = "0" + nextMonth ; //Add preceding "0" to single-digit month
   }

   var yearAndMonth = parseInt(thisYear+nextMonth); //Create integer of year+month

   $('#month option').each(function() { //Loop through all month options

      var selectMonth = $(this).prop('value'); //Get option value

      if (selectMonth.length == 1) {
         selectMonth = "0" + selectMonth; //Add preceding "0" to single-digit month
      }

      if (parseInt(selectedYear + selectMonth) < yearAndMonth) {
         $(this).hide(); //If the selected year + this month are less than the current year and month, hide this month
      } else {
         $(this).show(); //Otherwise, show it
      }

   });

   $("#month option").prop('selected', false); //Unselect all
   $("#month").find("option:visible:first").prop('selected', true); //Select first visible month from dropdown

}

$(document).ready(function() {
    adjustMonths(); //run script on pageload

    $('#year').change(function() {
      adjustMonths(); //run script when changing the year dropdown
    })

});
```

Comment: Works great! I will work on it a bit to see if I can refresh the month dropdown when selecting another year then going back to current year, but in essence it is the right answer. Also need to remove current month, but I should be able to figure that one easily. Thank you.

Comment: it has one bug as when you select other years from 2016 and then select any month afterwards when you select 2016 it will show you the month of january selected.

Comment: @RicardoAndres To remove current month, just set `thisMonth` to be `+2` instead of `+1`. I will fix the bug when going back to 2016.

Comment: If you want to leave the selected month instead of reverting to January when you move forward in years, here's a fiddle for that: https://jsfiddle.net/b7ua6jvv/3/

Comment: I am so grateful for this. Both of your final iterations work perfectly. TY

Comment: @RicardoAndres Not a problem! I don't think I put in a fail-safe in the event you do this in December - the month dropdown would be empty, however at that point I'd suggest just removing the current year from the `Year` dropdown completely as you can't choose it anyway.

Comment: @Santi Upon further testing, I found that Safari still shows the options that have the CSS of "display: none". I'll try the other solution listed below.

Comment: I am switching the correct answer to @JonathanGray. I hope you don't feel unappreciated. His solution is cross-browser compatible. Thank you for your help.